Polarized Bond and Bond Strength Relationship
So more polarized bonds are generally stronger ($\ce{C-O}$ bond energy $> \ce{C-C}$ bond energy), but more polarized bonds are also more reactive... is this something to simply accept?
So, taking the $\ce{C-O}$ and $\ce{C-C}$ as an example, $\ce{C-O}$ is a stronger bond but also more likely to be attacked by a nucleophile than $\ce{C-C}$. I suppose this depends on what we mean by reactivity.
